# VueJS quick render template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a way, similar to KnockoutJS to quick and easy render content from a template by Id?

```
<script type="text/html" id="template-example"><span>Hello world!</span></script>

<div data-bind="template: '#template-example'"></div>
```

I've read the documentation but did not find anything, and also tried to create a component called quick-template where the template attribute used a vale from props, but I did not render anything. Probably because the template is bound before props are populated

Version 2.6.12

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to Vue, the only reputable source is the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/options-rendering.html#template).

---

**In theory:**

The template is a core part of each vue component. In fact, a vue component won't render without one (or without a `render` function - which I consider just another way of providing a template, since that's what it returns).
It can can be provided as:

- `template: rawHTML` (HTML string)
- `template: '#some-id'` (where `#some-id` points to a `<template>`, `<script type="text/x-template">` or plain DOM element).
- `<template>content</template>` - in SFCs
- `render` function (returns an HTML string). Overrides any other form of providing a `template`.
- `el: '#some-id'`, the `template` consists of the `.innerHTML` of the DOM element with that `id` ***<sup>1, 2</sup>***.

I won't cover render functions, they're not relevant for your case. Vue parses both HTML and JSX. Vue loader accepts pre-processors, which makes it compatible with PUG, using a plugin.

---

**In practice:**

1. Register the templates as components, with the desired `template` attribute, alongside anything else they might need (`props`, `data`, `computed`, `methods`, `components`, `directives`, `filters`, `emits`, `watch`, `expose`, `compilerOptions`, `inheritAttrs`, `mixins`, `extends` and/or lifecycle hooks).
2. Use them in your app.

Demo ***<sup>3</sup>***:

```js
Vue.component('some-list', {
  template: '#some-list',
  props: ['powers']
})

Vue.component('some-item', {
  template: '#some-item',
  props: ['value']
})

Vue.component('svg-example', { 
  template: '#svg-example'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    myComponents: ['some-list', 'svg-example'],
    powers: 8
  }),
  methods: {
    getPowers(comp) {
      return (comp === 'some-list') && Number(this.powers)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
#app input {
  height: min-content;
}
#app div > div {
  padding: 3px 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span v-text="powers"></span>
  <input type="range" v-model="powers" min="2" max="12">
  <component v-for="component in myComponents"
             :powers="getPowers(component)"
             :key="component"
             :is="component" />
</div>

<template id="some-list">
  <div>
    <some-item v-for="(item, key) in powers" :key="key" :value="item" />
  </div>
</template>

<template id="some-item">
  <div v-text="Math.pow(2, value)" />
</template>

<template id="svg-example">
  <svg version="1.1"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 300 200"
       width="300">
    <image href="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
  </svg>
</template>
```

Same example ***<sup>4, 5</sup>***, registering the components on the app, not globally on Vue:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { 
    SomeList: {
      template: '#some-list',
      props: ['powers'],
      components: {
        SomeItem: {
          template: '<div v-text="Math.pow(2, value)" />',
          props: ['value']
        }
      }
    },
    SvgExample: {
      template: '#svg-example'
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    powers: 8
  })
})
```

```css
#app { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
#app input {
  height: min-content;
}
#app div > div {
  padding: 3px 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>{{powers}}</span>
  <input type="range" v-model="powers" min="2" max="12">
  <some-list :powers="Number(powers)"></some-list>
  <svg-example></svg-example>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="some-list">
  <div>
    <some-item v-for="(item, key) in powers" :key="key" :value="item" />
  </div>
</script>

<!-- innerHTML of this hidden div is used as template -->
<div id="svg-example" style="display: none">
  <svg version="1.1"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 300 200"
       width="300">
    <image href="https://picsum.photos/id/4/300/200" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

**Notes:**

***<sup>1</sup>*** - Only works inside `new Vue({})`.
***<sup>2</sup>*** - The placeholder (initial DOM element) will be replaced with the result of Vue's mounting process, so any event registered on the element prior to mounting will be lost.
***<sup>3</sup>*** - The template can be anywhere in DOM, not necessarily inside the Vue app.
***<sup>4</sup>*** - Less flexible (`SomeItem` component needs to be declared inside `SomeList` component, if declared in App, `<SomeList />` can't use it - not sure why, I'd have expected it to be available to child components).
***<sup>5</sup>*** - I've tweaked a few things with alternate syntaxes between the two examples, so you could compare them

Answer (score 0):

You could register a custom component and use the content of the script tag as template.

```
Vue.component('my-component', '#template-example');
```

Then somewhere in your Vue app:

```
<div id="app">
   <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```